# Columns are not adjusting in mobile view or small screen they are moving to next row in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

when i am inspecting the browser to see columns inside row they are not in a single line columns are moving to another line.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2  col-xs-5">
            <div class="brand-logo">
                <img src="logo.png" class="rounded-circle">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-7 col-md-7  col-xs-3">
            <div>smmm</div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-xs-4 ">
            <div class="right-header d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="header-account">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="header-cart">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which row is moving to another column? Is your image too big?

Comment: No image size is small actually it is i am using col-xs-* which is not correct,now i m using col-* in place of col-xs-* problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The mobile prefix in Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options) is not `.col-xs-` but `.col-`, so you just need to change all of the `col-xs-*` to `col-*`:

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-5">
                                          ^^
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-3">
                                          ^^
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-4">
                                          ^^
```

Comment: Thank u now all columns align in a single row in small screen.